# connect digital camera to python project

Tags: python, libgphoto2

Is it possible to read any camera (not a webcam) using Python language?
According to the answers I have found so far, I have tried to install the gphoto directory but I get an error message in the installation

```
<ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\gphoto2\setup.py", 
line 38, in <module> cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.') File 
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output **kwargs).stdout 
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
 as process: File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session) File 
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child startupinfo) 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifiedd the error message>.
```

I tried to download the library directly from Gitab and add it through the computer but also failed to install it in Python.
I work with the Windows operating system, PyCharm workspace, Python 3.6.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bit of that error message is `command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed`. The `pkg-config` command is standard on Linux, but you're using Windows.

According to the GPhoto FAQ (http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/FAQ.html#FAQ-Windows) Windows support is unlikely to happen. However you can install it with MSYS2 (http://www.msys2.org/) which also has Python etc. You will probably need to uninstall your camera's Windows driver. I'm not sure what else you'll need to do to get libgphoto2 talking to your camera.

[Edited to remove unhelpful suggestion and to add more background.]